# asp.net core EF fetching data from another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two models: Car.cs and SiteDefault.cs

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class SiteDefault
{
    public int SiteDefaultId { get; set; }
    public string MainPageBackgroundImg { get; set; }
    public string AboutPageBackgroundImg { get; set; }
    public string ContactPageBackgroundImg { get; set; }
}
```

In Views/Cars/Index.cshtml I am listing the cars easily with entity framework and I want to set its background image file name from SiteDefault table.

Actually I need to change my site's general settings (background, title etc.) dynamically and get them easily. There should be a best practice

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pull various bits of EF data into your view, you should create a ViewModel to represent all of the data you will need instead of trying to directly pass the EF entity into the view.  You cannot bind a view to multiple models, so you can't pull in the Car and SiteDefault models as two distinct entities.  The ViewModel is a new class that will hold this data.  If you plan on using most or all of the data in each of these two models, then you can create a ViewModel that just contains those two objects:

```
public class CarsViewModel {
   public Car Car { get; set; }
   public SiteDefault SiteDefault { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Cars controller, pull the data using EF and assign those objects to your ViewModel

```
var car = getCar() // EF
var siteDefault = getSiteDefault // more EF
var viewModel = new CarsViewModel() { Car = car, SiteDefault = siteDefault };
return View(viewModel);
```

In the view, you just put the @model statement at the top and use it in your view just like any other model (@Model.Car.CarName)

If you only plan on using a few fields from each class, then you can just create those fields in your ViewModel and not assign the entire object.  It's up to what works best for the situation.